# bokeh on_change for patches

Tags: python, bokeh

Using python 3.6 and bokeh 13.0.
I'm combining a bokeh patches to create a map of provinces and 
and bokeh circle to overlay the cities.

I want to use this map as interactive input filter for another plot.

When clicking cities is no problem, I get the name of the city.

When trying to do the same for a province, which is not a single point, but rather a polygon, I receive the following error message:

> error handling message Message 'PATCH-DOC' (revision 1): TypeError('list indices must be integers or slices, not list',)

I just want the index/name of the row. How should I approach this?

```
with open('map_NL_provinces.pickle', 'rb') as f:
        provinces = pickle.load(f)

with open('map_NL_cities.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    cities = pickle.load(f)

# renaming key in in dict
provinces['name'] = provinces.pop('names')

provinces = ColumnDataSource(data = provinces)

# from df to CDS
cities = ColumnDataSource(data=cities[['name','x','y']])

# plot map
f.patches('x', 'y', source=provinces,
          fill_color={'field': 'rate', 'transform': color_mapper},
          fill_alpha=1, line_color="black", line_width=1.5)

# plot cities
f.circle(x='x', y='y', source=cities, size=12, color=palette[3])

def callback_cities(attr, old, new):
    # This uses syntax for Bokeh >= 0.12.15
    print("Names of selected circles: {}".format(cities.data['name'][cities.selected.indices]))
    print("Indices of selected circles: ", cities.selected.indices)
    f.title.text=str(cities.data['name'][cities.selected.indices])

def callback_provinces(attr, old, new):
    # This uses syntax for Bokeh >= 0.12.15
    print("Names of selected provinces: {}".format(provinces.data['name'][provinces.selected.indices]))
    print("Indices of selected provinces: ", provinces.selected.indices)
    f.title.text=str(provinces.data['name'][provinces.selected.indices])

cities.on_change('selected', callback_cities)
provinces.on_change('selected', callback_provinces)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I was over thinking the problem. Taking the first entry of the list that is passed in a patch solves the problem for me.

Changing:

```
provinces.data['name'][provinces.selected.indices]
```

To:

```
provinces.data['name'][provinces.selected.indices[0]]
```